# Вывод расписания (универ)

Tags: php, база-данных, mysql

В БД расписание хранится в след виде:

```
id
Предмет
Преподаватель
группа
дата
время
кабинет
```

Отобразить необходимо в виде:

```
                                    группа
      Понедельник                                 Вторник                            
время  Предмет Преподаватель Кабинет         время Предмет Преподаватель Кабинет
```

Для начала мне понадобится скрипт, определения дня недели по времени.  Каким образом лучше отбирать данные? Найти последнюю дату в БД, и от нее отталкиваться? Например, найти последнюю дату, узнать что это пятница, и двигаться назад до понедельника?
Расписание постоянно обновляется.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RTFM, "скрипт, определения дня недели по времени":

```
string date ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )
date('w'); // 0 - воскресенье .. 6 - суббота
```

Чтобы отобразить - выбрать всё для одной группы (параметр которой передан) и сформировать расписание по дням недели.

Comment: А как во всей базе определить последнюю дату?
Хранится дата в стринг типа 29/12/20012

Comment: И как лучишь хранить дату? В виде unix значения?

Comment: Тут кому как привычнее. В принципе есть функции форматирования даты и им всё-равно как хранить, главное - показать как отображать. В БД иногда без бубна не обходится, чтобы сортировать НЕ UnixTimestamp. Если mysql, то советую именно UnixTimestamp

Comment: В SQL базе для хранения даты можно выбирать из [нескольких](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-type-overview.html) типов данных. 

IMHO надо стремиться использовать встроенные в СУБД типы (например DATETIME) и по максимуму  применять запросы SQL.